# MySQL - Something wrong with my join

Tags: mysql, sql

Been puzzling over this for a while now.

Basically here's my statement.

```
SELECT CandidateID, Town, Candidates.SalaryMin, CandidateExperience, CandidateExperience.divTagExp, PrimarySector, Candidates.SalaryMin, CandidateSalary.divTagSal, 
CASE WHEN following.RecID =1
THEN  'block'
ELSE  'none'
END AS divFollow
FROM Candidates
LEFT JOIN CandidateExperience ON CandidateExperience.CandidateExpID = Candidates.CandidateExperience
LEFT JOIN CandidateSalary ON Candidates.SalaryMin >= CandidateSalary.SalaryMin
LEFT JOIN following ON following.RecID = Candidates.CandidateID
AND Candidates.SalaryMin <= CandidateSalary.SalaryMax
```

Here's my Candidates table:

[image]

Here's my following table:

[image]

Here's my results of the query:

[image]

I know there's something wrong with the join, but I've tried left, right, inner, outer and none of them of giving me what I want.

What I do want is, one entry for each entry in the Candidates, with the divFollow field showing 'block', if there's a matching entry in 'following' and 'none' if there isn't.

What am I missing?

Thank you!

UPDATE:

New result set after adjusting RecID to FollowingID

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a few records from CandidateExperience and CandidateSalary. As far as i can see its there (The CandidateSalary join) that's causing problems. Try it without that join.

Comment: It was fine with those joins. It's just when adding the following join it started sending multiple results. Sorry should have been clearer on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *,
        CASE
        WHEN    candidateId IN
                (
                SELECT  followId
                FROM    following
                )
                THEN
                'block'
        ELSE
                'none'
        END AS divFollow
FROM    Candidates
```

Comment: This has done it. I try to avoid using sub queries but I can't think of another way around it at this point. Thank you.

Comment: @Mcam435: there is a way using `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`, but there's nothing bad in subqueries

Answer (score 1):

```
select Candidates.*, ISNULL(Following.divFollow, 'none') as divFollow
from Candidates left join (select distinct followID from Following) as Following
    on CandidateID = followID
```

Further inner joins can be made to get data from Following table.

Left outer join ensures that all entries in the former table (left side of join operator) will be in the resulting table at least one. If there is no correspondent in the later (right side of the join operator) table the cells coming from the later table are filled with NULL. This gets the job done for you since you want for each Candidate having a correspondent in Following to get a 'block', otherwise 'none', value on divFollow.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

the following join condition:

```
LEFT JOIN following ON following.RecID = Candidates.CandidateID
```

should be:

```
LEFT JOIN following ON following.FollowID= Candidates.CandidateID
```

Also:

```
AND Candidates.SalaryMin <= CandidateSalary.SalaryMax
```

should be here:

```
LEFT JOIN CandidateSalary ON Candidates.SalaryMin >= CandidateSalary.SalaryMin AND Candidates.SalaryMin <= CandidateSalary.SalaryMax
```

Comment: Ah yes that was a problem. Fixed that but still getting multiple records, will upload the new results.

Comment: The AND Candidates.SalaryMin <= CandidateSalary.SalaryMax is still part of that JOIN, it's just the way MySQL formats it.

Comment: If you want a single row per candidate, then you need to either exclude the salary, or aggregate it.. you have multiples because Bill Bridge has multiple entries in the salary table..

Answer (score 0):

You're joining with `following ON following.RecID = Candidates.CandidateID` - I guess you wanted something more like `following ON following.followID = Candidates.CandidateID`.

Also, if you don't want the divTagSal, you can use `GROUP BY` to put them all together.

Comment: I need the divTagSal unfortunately.